# add-apt-repository now broken after python was updated

Tags: apt, python, repository

Add-apt-repository no longer works after an update.  I see a python3.8 folder now and I had 3 python modules updated.
I have spent a couple of days so far trying various suggested fixes with symbolic links and reinstalling most of python.  Nothing has worked.  Most of the suggested fixes are from several years ago and not pertinent to the python versions installed now.

The modules that were updated and probably the root cause are:

python3-distutils:amd64 (3.6.8-1~18.04, 3.6.9-1~18.04)
python3-lib2to3:amd64 (3.6.8-1~18.04, 3.6.9-1~18.04)
python3-gdbm:amd64 (3.6.8-1~18.04, 3.6.9-1~18.04)

I had used the add-apt-repository recently, only a couple of weeks ago to add a new repository with no issues.  Never had any issues before either.

I have python2.7, python3, python3.6, python3.7 and now python3.8  None were manually installed.  All came from automatic updates.

`python3 -V` yields Python 3.6.8

This is the error that I get with the add-apt-repository command:

```
keith@Serenity:/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:sicklylife/gnucash
^CTraceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/add-apt-repository", line 136, in <module>
    shortcut = shortcut_handler(line)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/SoftwareProperties.py", line 868, in shortcut_handler
    ret = factory(shortcut)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/ppa.py", line 398, in shortcut_handler
    return PPAShortcutHandler(shortcut)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/ppa.py", line 355, in __init__
    info = get_ppa_info(self.shortcut)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/ppa.py", line 326, in get_ppa_info
    ret = get_ppa_info_from_lp(user, ppa)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/ppa.py", line 101, in get_ppa_info_from_lp
    return get_info_from_lp(lp_url)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/ppa.py", line 95, in get_info_from_lp
    return get_info_from_https(lp_url, True)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/ppa.py", line 88, in get_info_from_https
    data = _get_https_content_py3(url, accept_json)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/ppa.py", line 120, in _get_https_content_py3
    lp_page = urllib.request.urlopen(request, cafile=LAUNCHPAD_PPA_CERT)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 223, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 526, in open
    response = self._open(req, data)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 544, in _open
    '_open', req)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 504, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 1361, in https_open
    context=self._context, check_hostname=self._check_hostname)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 1318, in do_open
    encode_chunked=req.has_header('Transfer-encoding'))
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 1254, in request
    self._send_request(method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 1300, in _send_request
    self.endheaders(body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 1249, in endheaders
    self._send_output(message_body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 1036, in _send_output
    self.send(msg)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 974, in send
    self.connect()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 1407, in connect
    super().connect()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 946, in connect
    (self.host,self.port), self.timeout, self.source_address)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/socket.py", line 713, in create_connection
    sock.connect(sa)
KeyboardInterrupt
keith@Serenity:/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages$
```

Comment: What release are you running?  Various 18.04 packages are listed, but are you running 18.04?

Comment: Yes. Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS  Any other pertinent information do you need to help troubleshoot why this basic function does not work?

Comment: Anybody else want to try and help?  I can't leave this broken as I really need to add another ppa repository.

Comment: What do you get for `python -V`

Comment: keith@Serenity:~$ python -V
Python 2.7.15+

Comment: python3 -V
Python 3.6.8